# How can I move sprite diagonally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, character, sprite, move

The character moves in each direction, but how can I hold another key to allow it to move diagonally rather than just stop and move in that direction?  I set up a gif here: https://i.gyazo.com/1a13d207f94e4361ab8e015679ba5d85.gif

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        
       $("#character").addClass("front-stand");
        
    });
    
        //setInterval(moveChar, 20);
   
    var keypressed = 0;
    
    
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        
        if (!keypressed){
            
            keypressed = e.keyCode;
            moveChar();
           
            
            if (e.keyCode == keypressed){
                keypressed = false;
                $("#character").stop(false,true);
            }
            
            
            function moveChar(){
        
            switch (e.keyCode){
                    
                case 38:
                    $("#character").animate({top: "-=25"}, 200);
                break;
                    
                case 39:
                    $("#character").animate({left: "+=25"}, 200);
                break;
                    
                case 40:
                    $("#character").animate({top: "+=25"}, 200);
                break;
                    
                case 37:
                    $("#character").animate({left: "-=25"}, 200);
                break;    
    
           }
        
        
    }
            
            
        }
        
    });


#character{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-image:url(character.png);
    
 }
```

Comment: As I am currently unable to provide a working model (lack of time) what you need to do, from what I have attempted quickly to do, is make it monitor both on key down and on key up. Continue the effects so long as the key is down, cancel it on the up.

Comment: Alright I will keep trying, I have no intention to give up until I figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I am not saying that the following is perfect, but I did manage to get it working quickly after some fiddling. I've posted it to codepen, so you should be able to see it whenever, but I've also got it here just in case. Odds are there is probably a much cleaner and nicer way to do this, but so far this is what I've got.

### Some Random Bugs I've Noticed

If you hit two keys at the same time, it will first register the sideways motion for 1 animation and will THEN animate both motions after that. You could probably clear this up by calling a delay on for say 100ms, but I didn't get a chance to test how that does.

### [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/jhechtf/pen/OMwKNo)

```js
function _animate(el, key) {
  if (key < 37 || key > 40) return undefined;
  el = $(el);
  var styles = {};
  if (el.data('animations') == undefined)
    el.data('animations', []);
  var data = el.data('animations');
  if (data.indexOf(key) == -1)
    data.push(key);
  el.data('animations', data); //Push the object to the element.
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var k = data[i]
    switch (k) {
      case 37:
        styles.left = '-=25px';
        break;
      case 38:
        styles.top = '-=25px';
        break;
      case 39:
        styles.left = '+=25px';
        break;
      case 40:
        styles.top = '+=25px';
        break;
    }
  }

  console.log(styles);
  el.animate(styles);

}
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  _animate($('#sprite'), e.keyCode);
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
  data = $('#sprite').data('animations');
  data.splice(data.indexOf(e.keyCode), 1);
  $('#sprite').clearQueue();
});
```

```css
div#sprite {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sprite">&nbsp;</div>
```